# Is there a special way to declare/define C++ constructors (and destructors)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constructor, destructor, typedef

*EDIT: This is a discussion about best practice in the (simplified) case presented below. Whatever tool, coding style or something else you want to suggest, post it. Thanks.*

Why are there no special ways to declare or define ctors/dtors without duplicating the name of the class? It's annoying, especially when prototyping and ending up changing the name of the class a lot.

What I mean is something with *typedef* like this:

```
struct SomeClassThatDoesSomething {
    typedef SomeClassThatDoesSomething ThisClass;
    ThisClass() { PrepareToDie(); }
    ThisClass(int a) : _a(a) { PrepareToDie(); }
    ThisClass(float a, int b) : _b(a), _a(b) { PrepareToDie(); }
    ThisClass(float a, char * b) : _b(a), _c(b) { PrepareToDie(); }
    ThisClass(char * a, int b) : _c(a), _a(b) { PrepareToDie(); }
    ThisClass(ThisClass &rhs) {  }
    ~ThisClass() {}
    void Burn() {}
    void PrepareToDie() {}
    int _a;
    float _b;
    char *_c;
};

struct SomeDerivedClassThatDoesSomething : public SomeClassThatDoesSomething {
    typedef ThisClass BaseClass;
    typedef SomeDerivedClassThatDoesSomething ThisClass;
    ThisClass(BaseClass &is_not_amused) : BaseClass(is_not_amused) { BaseClass::_a = 1; PrepareToDie(); }
    ThisClass(float a, char * b) : BaseClass(b, a) {}
    ~ThisClass() { BaseClass::Burn(); }
    unsigned int _a; // Different semantics up the tree.
};

//EDIT: Consider this: Enforce export name decoration policy.
#define DLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
// ... or dllimport - not the point here
#define def_export_struct( name ) struct C##name; typedef C##name *P##name; struct DLL_API C##name 

def_export_struct( SomeOtherClassThatDoesSomething ) : public SomeDerivedClassThatDoesSomething 
{
//...
};
namespace mass_destruction {
    def_export_struct( Int )
    {
    //... (The point is that search and replace gets very unreliable in big projects)
    }
};
```

It only works for ctors and only on MSVC; I've been using it and, although not a big feature, it makes life easier. This is a trivial example, but imagine a fairly complicated structure.
(A handy side-effect is also that you have an alias in class without having to track its name.) **Am I missing something? Am I really the only one who needs this?** The point is not whether it compiles, the point is that I've got it partly working all over the place for me and it does wonders. Until I hit the standard... **(This is not a compliance discussion.)**

Comment: Modern IDEs have decent refactoring capabilities (or there are plugins which provide them), so renaming a class becomes very simple. Hence, I see no need for such a feature.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. Whether such a feature exists, or *why* it doesn't exist, something else? And by saying you already know of such a feature and you're not interested in compliance, it's hard to know what more you want.

Comment: @BjörnPollex: refactoring capabilites for C++ are generally lagging far behind their Java/C# counterparts. And that aside, not everyone use IDEs at all, and it's hardly the purpose of an IDE to make language improvements *unnecessary*

Comment: And what if you use a #define def_entity( name ) struct C##name; typedef C##name *P##name; struct C##name  // I've never seen refactoring for this. Are we using same language?

Comment: @user1240436: Any decent editor will allow you to change the name of a class (and all usages) quickly: My editor `/class OldName<enter>my/};<enter>:'y,. s/OldName/NewName/g` and if you want to be insane and use macros then you deserve any associated problems.

Comment: Well, my life gets easier by using this macro. No case for insanity here.

Comment: @user1240436 If you wrote this and worked for me I might fire you.

Comment: Good that I don't work for you, sir.

Comment: Also, if you are constantly changing your classes names over and over, you might want to stop coding for a while and really think about your design.

Comment: Are you implying that STL is easier to read? It's a monument of best naming convention practices ever, really.

Comment: This "question" does not lead anywhere, does it?

Comment: [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/products/featureRefactoring.asp) has a very good 'rename' feature. I press alt+shift+r when my cursor is on a symbol and type the new name. poof. It takes all of 2 seconds (versus the 5 seconds find&replace would take). Don't clutter your code to drop 5 seconds from your development process.

Comment: @Andre I got all the information I need.

Answer (score 6):

Ever heard of search-and-replace?

I guess that most people either use `ex`, `vim`, `sed`. etc: `s/search/replace/g` or equivalent to change the name of their classes, or don't change them that often to be upset by the lack of this feature.

You could use a `#define` to do this compliantly:

```
#define THIS_CLASS MyLongClassNameThatIChangeLotsAndLots
class THIS_CLASS{
    THIS_CLASS() { PrepareToDie(); }
    THIS_CLASS(int a) : _a(a) { PrepareToDie(); }
    THIS_CLASS(float a, int b) : _b(a), _a(b) { PrepareToDie(); }
    THIS_CLASS(float a, char * b) : _b(a), _c(b) { PrepareToDie(); }
    THIS_CLASS(char * a, int b) : _c(a), _a(b) { PrepareToDie(); }
    THIS_CLASS(THIS_CLASS &rhs) {  }
    ~THIS_CLASS() {}
};
#undef THIS_CLASS
```

What is upsetting, I'll agree, is the lack of a standard way to refer to the base class(es) of a type -- I normally privately `typedef ... base_t` in classes, then use that for initialiser lists, etc.

Comment: I also use sed, but it is not available in some systems. Your macro doesn't help much because classes may have distinct constructors. You can't assume even a minimal set of common ctors. I personally think it's not worth the time.

Comment: Another problem is that macro redefinition gets ugly with #pragma push_macro( "THIS_CLASS" ) and #pragma pop_macro( "THIS_CLASS" ). Doable, but harder to track. I would save such a thing for less than common definitions.

Comment: @UmNyobe you should've upvoted the question which already contains `PrepareToDie()`

Answer (score 3):

If your class names are getting frustratingly long-winded, **consider making more use of `namespace`.**

`namespace`, combined with `using` is great for making your typenames only as verbose as each context demands.

```
namespace Something
{
  struct Derived : public SomeClass
  {
     Derived() {...etc.}

  }
}
```

Comment: The long names are over the top on purpose. But back to your answer: Doesn't this actually make search & replace harder? It would introduce many duplicate names.

Comment: @user1240436: It does make s/r harder, yes.  My answer doesn't really apply after your edit.

Comment: It's still useful as a way to plan a smaller project.